# Rails 5 - ActionCable client with pure WebSocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to use a pure WebSocket library (browser or whatever) to connect to a channel from action cable in Rails ?

Am I tied to libs like:
https://github.com/tomchinery/action-cable-node
https://www.npmjs.com/package/actioncable-js
or 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/actioncable

?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. [ActionCable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actioncable) is the official compiled javascript of the coffee support provided by [rails - npmified](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/package.json) version through sprockets.

All you have to do is install it, require and

```
var ActionCable = require('actioncable')
var cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('wss://mydomain.com/cable')

     cable.subscriptions.create({ channel: 'ChatChannel' }, {
       received: (data) => {
         console.log(data);
       }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. I think you can find a good example here, but I still haven't tested it:
[Consuming Rails 5 Action Cable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185275/consuming-rails-5-actioncable).

I think is possible to consume Action Cable endpoint outside from the coffee / Rails frontend framewrok, it's just an hack to turn it working.

If you have better resources, feel free to share.